# How do I simplify this code to reduce the amount of lines necessary? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://plnkr.co/V14X7icWCrmUw6IrCRVV

That's the plunker for the code. I've never linked to plunker so if it doesn't work, let me know.

What it is supposed to do is when a user hovers over some of the text, that same text should appear in the yellow box.

I thought I should have been able to do it with just a few lines, and substituting the index number with a variable, and looping through them with a while loop. I couldn't quite figure it out and had to just make like 20 different functions. I got it to do what I wanted it to do, but I can't help but think there should be a simpler way to do it.

Here is the Javascript: (The plunker link has the CSS and HTML)

```
   var gamesArray = ['Metal Gear Solid 1', 'The Last of Us', 'Uncharted', 'Snake Eater', 'Need for Speed', 'Forza', 'Halo', 'Conker\'s Bad Fur Day', 'WWF No Mercy', 'WWF Wrestlemania 2000', 'Spelunky', 'The Last of Us Part 2', 'The Walking Dead Season 1', 'The Phantom Pain', 'Ys Memories of Celceta', 'Ys Seven', 'Dragon Ball Z Tenkaichi Tag Team', 'Naruto: Ultimate Ninja Heroes', 'Mortal Kombat'];

var itemList = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var box2 = document.getElementsByClassName('answerBox');
    box2[0].style.borderColor = 'black';
    box2[0].style.color = 'red';

    //var num = 0;  
    //var i = itemList[num];
    //var j = gamesArray[num];



function choice000(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[0];

        }

function choice001(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[1];
        }

function choice002(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[2];
        }

function choice003(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[3];
        }

function choice004(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[4];
        }

function choice005(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[5];
        }

function choice006(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[6];
        }

function choice007(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[7];
        }

function choice008(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[8];
        }

function choice009(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[9];
        }

function choice010(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[10];
        }

function choice011(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[11];
        }

function choice012(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[12];
        }

function choice013(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[13];
        }

function choice014(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[14];
        }

function choice015(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[15];
        }

function choice016(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[16];
        }

function choice017(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[17];
        }

function choice018(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[18];
        }

function choice019(){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[19];
        }
```

Comment: `function choice(item_no){
box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[item_no];
}`

Answer (score 0):

Just use one function:

```
function choice(game){
   box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[game];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function choice(number) {
    box2[0].textContent = gamesArray[number];
}
```

Use this function and then replace any of the other function calls. Example choice003() is replaced with choice(3)

Answer (score 0):

I like that you doubt your solution, because it is indeed overwhelming! It's a very important rule: if you see certain pattern, repetition of some kind, you can always make it shorter.

First of all, you need to decide if your items are already created in HTML or do you want to create them using JavaScript. In other words: you should have only one source of data. In your example you'd need to maintain two data sources at once — array in JavaScript and list in HTML.

## HTML-driven data

It's extremely important to separate HTML and JavaScript as much as possible. Below you'll find a working example without even a smallest amount of any JS functions or events.

If you design your code that way it's easier to keep track of everything, as it stays simple. JavaScript code below has only around 6 real-lines and it can be simplified even more!

If you need to provide any additional data in the box, that are not visible to the user by default, you can use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

I've used [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/) since I'm used to it, but you can easily achieve the same effect with roughly the same amount of lines with [pure JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

```js
/*
  We define every event and action only in JavaScript.
  We're keeping HTML *pure* and *simple*.
*/

$(function(){
  var $games = $('.gameChoiceList li');
  
  $games.on('mouseover', function() {  // After moving mouse on any [.gameChoiceList li] element
    var $game = $(this);
    var $result = $('.answerBox');
    
    $result.text($game.text());        // Display current [.gameChoiceList li] text in [.answerBox]
  });
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */
body {
  background-color: skyblue;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;  /*
     We provide feedback if user doesn't have Arial font installed:
     sans-serif is a group of serif fonts, so possible replacement wont be far from Arial */
}

.answerContainer{ /*
     We don't need width: auto; and height: auto; as those are the default values */
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.testAnswer{
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.answerBox{
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

/*/ Extra: /*/
.gameChoiceList {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  width: 40%;
}
.gameChoiceList li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 2px;
}
.gameChoiceList li a {
  display: block;
  border: solid 1px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
.answerBox {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="gameChoiceList">
  <!--
    We don't need the same class for every <li>, as it is easily accesible by:
          .gameChoiceList li    OR    .gameChoiceList > li
    
    We don't need the same class for every <a>, as it is easily accesible by:
          .gameChoiceList li a    OR    .gameChoiceList a
  -->
  <li><a href="#">Metal Gear Solid 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">The Last of Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Uncharted</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Snake Eater</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Need for Speed</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Forza</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Halo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Conker's Bad Fur Day</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">WWF No Mercy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">WWF Wrestlemania 2000</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Spelunky</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">The Last of Us Part 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">The Walking Dead Season 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ys Memories of Celceta</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ys Seven</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dragon Ball Z Tenkaichi Tag Team</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Naruto Ultimate Ninja Heroes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Mortal Kombat</a></li>
</ul>

<p class="answerBox">Mouseover on any of the games on the side to display its name here.</p>
```

## Extra thought

I noticed that in your JavaScript code you're changing `borderColor` and `color` of `.answerBox`. **You should never do that**.

As it's part of visual styles, you should define adequate styles beforehand in your CSS file and then, toggle certain classes as needed. For example, below code is much easier to maintain:

```js
/*/
  Of course all the code below can be simplified to just 1 line:
      document.querySelector('p').className = 'important';
      
  I wanted to show something universal that helps separate the logic even more:
  You can pass any element, class and content to the make() function.
/*/

var make = function(element, className, content) {
  element.className = className;
  element.textContent = content;
};

var paragraph = document.querySelector('p');

setTimeout(function() {
  make(paragraph, 'important', 'Important paragraph');
}, 1000);  // Make important after 1 second

setTimeout(function() {
  make(paragraph, 'irrelevant', 'Irrelevant paragraph. do dont read it!');
}, 2000);  // Make important after 2 seconds
```

```css
/*/ Since we defined every class beforehand,
    it's easier to adjust styles for certain actions in the future /*/

p {
  color: green;
}

p.important {
  color: red;
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 10px;
}

p.irrelevant {
  color: gray;
  font-size: .8em;
}
```

```html
<p>Very nice paragraph</p>
```

*Stay pure!

~Wiktor*

Comment: That's a great explanation. Thanks for taking the time to do that. It was very helpful.

Why is editing CSS through Javascript looked down on? Are there any particular bad side effects that can occur?

Comment: It is considered a bad practice to mix-up presentation layer (CSS) with content (HTML) and behaviour (JS) layers. By putting inline CSS code directly in your HTML or JS you're losing the benefits of using the same styles on several elements. In turn, it can lead to duplicated code and make changing styles a lot harder in the future. Also, there may be some caching and bandwidth disadvantages. You can learn more about **separation of concerns** in [this question](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/271338) and [this article](http://keithjgrant.com/posts/against-css-in-js.html).